# way to optimize / make shorter this code fragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a couple of classes that take a Ruby hash and make an Address out of it. It looks like the following:

```
  class Address
    attr_accessor :distance_between

    attr_reader :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :city

    def initialize parsed
      @distance_between = nil
      @id = parsed["id"]
      @address_line1 = parsed["address_line1"]
      @address_line2 = parsed["address_line2"]
      @city = parsed["city"]
```

Is there a slick Ruby way to optimize this to less lines? It is in Rails so will have all helpers. And the attributes have the same name as the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you would typically do this is:

```
class Address
  attr_accessor :distance_between, 
                :id, 
                :address_line1, 
                :address_line2, 
                :city
  
  def initialize(**attrs)
    attrs.each { |k,v| send("#{k}=", v) }
  end
end
```

The reason you want to call setters instead of setting the instance variables directly is that it lets you override the behavior on a per variable level. This how Rails does it in [ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html).

Since this is a Rails question there is really is no reason to be reinventing the wheel - use ActiveModel::Model instead.

```
class Address
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :distance_between
  attribute :id
  attribute :address_line1 
  attribute :address_line2
  attribute :city
end
```

This gives you support for typecasting, defaults and serialization.

Of course none of this is needed if its an ActiveRecord model backed by a database table.

ActiveModel doesn't have a straight forward way to define read only attributes like [ActiveRecord does](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html) but you can hack something together:

```
module ActiveModel
  class ReadOnlyAttributeException < StandardError
  end
end

class Address
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :distance_between
  attribute :id
  attribute :address_line1 
  attribute :address_line2
  attribute :city

  def initialize(**attributes)
    super 
    @_initialized = true
  end

  private

  def id=(value)
    raise ReadOnlyException if  @_initialized
    super
  end
end
```

Or the same idea as above with some metaprogramming magic:

```
module ReadOnlyAttributes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def initialize(**attributes)
    super 
    @_initialized = true
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attr_readonly(*attrs)
      attrs.each do |attr|
        define_method("#{attr}=") do
          raise ReadOnlyException if  @_initialized
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Address
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ReadOnlyAttributes

  attribute :distance_between
  attribute :id
  attribute :address_line1 
  attribute :address_line2
  attribute :city

  attr_readonly :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :city
end
```

Comment: thx - certainly don't want to reinvent the wheel. In your ActiveModel::Model, would those attributes be read only? Could we specify that and have some be read/write and others read only?

Comment: I edited the question and added an example of how you can do read only attributes with ActiveModel. Its slightly more involved then with ActiveRecord as it doesn't actually keep track of the lifecycle of the model in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `instance_variable_set` method

```
class Address
    # distance_between will be nil by default, 
    # so you don't need to initialize it 
    # to nil in the initializer
    attr_accessor :distance_between
      
    attr_reader :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :city

    def initialize(parsed)
      %w[id address_line1 address_line2 city].each do |attr|
        instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", parsed[attr])
      end
   end
end
```

In case you want to assign **all** the keys of the address hash to the instance variables of the class, you can do this:

```
def initialize(parsed)
  parsed.each { |attr, val| instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", val) }
end
```